# iOS 11 SDK "Expected a type" Compile Error

Tags: ios, swift

I'm facing a strange "Expected a type" Error in Xcode 9.4.1 while compiling this project, which was once started as an objective-c project.
The file I'm looking at is an .h file, in a lib in the project. Normally this error was related to any messed up parentheses, but I can't see anything, nor has the file been touched since years.
[image]

```
#import "DDXMLDocument.h"

@interface DDXMLDocument (MKPAdditions)

- (id)initWithReadIO:(xmlInputReadCallback)ioread closeIO:(xmlInputCloseCallback)ioclose context:(void*)ioctx options:(NSUInteger)mask error:(NSError **)error;

@end
```

Can anyone explain what this error means?

As it is getting more weird for me,
I found another error which actually comes behind the one described above at build time:

```
DDXMLDocument *document = [[DDXMLDocument alloc] initWithReadIO:readCallback
                                                         closeIO:closeCallback
                                                         context:(__bridge void *)(inputStream)
                                                         options:0
                                                           error:nil];
```

[image: second error]

Complete error description:

> Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type 'int (*)(void *, char *, int)' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC

So I assume it has something to do with the MAC Upgrade and the latest compiler version now used.

Comment: Why is this tagged Swift? Why had you indicated in your post that the code is Swift source code? This is a .h file. This is an Objective-C header file.

Comment: @rmaddy, it is a swift project. as this is core here I think the tag has to be set this way.

Comment: I would guess there's another header that used to be included in the bridging header, but has been removed. e.g. `xmlInputReadCallback` is now undefined.

Comment: thanks @GrahamPerks, I found another error to this reference, though it is happening behind the implementation. I added it to the main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import missing, that was becoming necessary, all other errors have been follow up failures. --> close